# H doesn't take cursor to top of screen

Tags: vim

I've read that `H` should make the cursor go to the top of the current screen. Also `L` doesn't goto bottom of current screen. However, `M` does goto middle of current screen. How can I fix this? Or find out hat the actual mapping is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HML` are not mappings; they are hardcoded commands. But some plugins or your own configuration can create mappings that override those default commands.

This command tells you where a mapping was last set and what it does:

```
:verbose map H
```

Comment: Wow, the three of us are all in top form again today! Three identical answers within a minute!

Comment: I almost heard the sound of your keyboard and Kent's while typing my answer. ;-)

Comment: @romainl oh, next time I should switch the microphone off! >:-|

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the normal suspicions about an interfering mapping given in other answers, you may have your `'scrolloff'` option set to some non-zero value. When this option is set to *N*, Vim always keeps *N* lines of text between the cursor and the top/bottom of the window. As you scroll, this means that the text scrolls when the cursor reaches a line within *N* lines of the top/bottom, but when using <kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>L</kbd>, it means the cursor will only *move* to within *N* lines of the top/bottom of the window.

In particular, if `'scrolloff'` is set higher than the window height, then your cursor always stays in the middle of the screen as you scroll, and <kbd>H</kbd>/<kbd>L</kbd> do nothing at all.

Comment: That's a good alternative diagnosis! (Though the poster would have probably complained that `j` / `k` don't allow to position the cursor anywhere other than the middle line, and cause scrolling instead.)

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\defaults.vim` for example (which gets sourced by `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\vimrc_example.vim`, which I choose to source) sets `scrolloff=5`. I reset it to 0.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds that there is mapping that overwritten the default `H, L` function.

you can use `:verbose map H` to find out the current key mapping on `H` and where it was done.

Answer (score 5):

It's likely that a plugin has remapped those two keys. You can find out with

```
:verbose map H
:verbose map L
```